Issue with passing UTC time as Custom Header - Named Credentials
I have set up a named credential to call an external system and this need few Authorization headers for Authentication. One of the parameters related to Authentication is passing the current time in UTC format.
Ex:

2024-05-07T08:59:54.645Z

With the Standard TEXT(NOW()) logic, I get the below result

2024-05-07 14:58:09Z

So I created a formula which results details

{!LEFT(TEXT( NOW() ),10 ) & "T" & LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(NOW()),9),8) & ".000Z"}


2024-05-07T08:59:54.645Z

But when I tried to use the same formula through Custom headers it just gave the response as 401(It means the SF is not taking the parsing correctly through custom headers)

Response I see flow debug

Does anyone tried to pass the custom header with UTC time as a parameter? Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

it just gave the response as 401(It means the SF is not taking the parsing correctly through custom headers - how did you arrive at this conclusion?

I updated my question and included the flow debug response. I am getting 200 response when I write apex code

Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
